# How to insert a character into a string every 3 characters from the right

Tags: sql-server, string

I have a string made up of numbers. The length of the string ranges anywhere from 1 character to 9 characters.
I want to insert a dash (-) every three characters from the right. This will only be relevant for strings with upwards of three characters.
This will just be a select statement, as I do not want to actually update the string itself.

For example,

```
8 should return 8
476 should return 476
4767 should return 4-767
45907392 should return 45-907-392
845907392 should return 845-907-392
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
select 
  *,
  replace(format(n,'#,#'),',','-')
from (values (8),(476),(4767),(45907392),(845907392)) x (n)
```

Change , to . if it's thousand separator in your system, or provide a culture as third parameter in FORMAT function so it always works the same.

Answer (score 1):

Since SQL Server 2012 you can use the `FORMAT` function as described in the other answers. In case you want to format a string value like 'abcde' too you can use only string functions like this:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100) = '845907392';

-- 845-907-392
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@str), 7, 3)) 
  + CASE WHEN LEN(@str)>6 THEN '-' ELSE '' END 
  + REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@str), 4, 3)) 
  + CASE WHEN LEN(@str)>3 THEN '-' ELSE '' END 
  + REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@str), 1, 3))
```

You can also create a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetFormatTripleDash (@str varchar(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @retStr VARCHAR(255) = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@str), 7, 3)) 
    + CASE WHEN LEN(@str)>6 THEN '-' ELSE '' END 
    + REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@str), 4, 3)) 
    + CASE WHEN LEN(@str)>3 THEN '-' ELSE '' END 
    + REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@str), 1, 3))
  RETURN(@retStr)
END
```

You can use this funtion like this:

```
-- 845-907-392
SELECT dbo.GetFormatTripleDash('845907392')
```

---

A more flexible solution using the function. Now you can use a much longer string value and you can define the part size separated by `-` character.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetFormatDash (@str varchar(255), @partSize INT = 3)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @startSize INT = 0;
  DECLARE @retStr VARCHAR(255) = '';

  WHILE @startSize < LEN(@str)
  BEGIN
    SET @retStr = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@str), @startSize + 1, @partSize)) + CASE WHEN @startSize > 0 THEN '-' ELSE '' END + @retStr;
    SET @startSize = @startSize + @partSize;
  END

  RETURN(@retStr)
END
```

You can use this improved function like this:

```
-- 12-345-678-901-234-567-890
SELECT dbo.GetFormatDash('12345678901234567890', DEFAULT)
SELECT dbo.GetFormatDash('12345678901234567890', 3)

-- 12345-67890-12345-67890
SELECT dbo.GetFormatDash('12345678901234567890', 5)
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1eed0d94012e93a98dba352997f924cd)

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `format()` function.

```
Select Replace(format(8, '#,##0'), ',', '-')
Select Replace(format(476, '#,##0'), ',', '-')
Select Replace(format(45907392, '#,##0'), ',', '-')
Select Replace(format(845907392, '#,##0'), ',', '-')
```

Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a4a9a188936d9308c5ed90bf2ddff562) demo.

[image]

Comment: @DougCoats I have edited the answer with the demo I think it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit gross but it works! Try i
t and let me know if you agree

```
    SELECT
        CASE    
            WHEN LEN(yourColumn)>6 THEN format(CAST(YourColumn AS NUMERIC), '###-###-###') 
            WHEN LEN(YourColumn)>3 THEN format(CAST(YourColumn AS NUMERIC), '###-###')
            ELSE YourColumn
        END
```

Here is another way to do it, albeit more typing

```
    SELECT
        CASE    
            WHEN LEN(yourColumn)>6 THEN SUBSTRING(YourColumn, 1, 3) +'-'+ SUBSTRING(YourColumn, 4, 3)
            WHEN LEN(YourColumn)>3 THEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(YourColumn), 1, 3) +'-'+ SUBSTRING(REVERSE(YourColumn), 4, 3))
            ELSE YourColumn
        END
```

Comment: Thanks Doug,
It says 'Argument data type nvarchar is invalid for argument 1 of format function.'. The field is actually text and not numerical.

Comment: @Dan see edited answer - format can only be used with dates and numerics. You can actually rewrite this whole select to use substring as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I'm sure it can also be extended to allow for any number of characters with a bit of effort

```
declare @input nvarchar(100) = '845907392'
declare @separator char(1) = '-'

--option1 - CTE

;with dash1 as (
    select isnull(stuff(reverse(@input), 1+3, 0, @separator), reverse(@input)) as v
)
, dash2 as(
    select isnull(stuff(v, 1+7, 0, @separator), v) as v from dash1
)
select reverse(v) from dash2


--option2 - Non CTE
select reverse(isnull(stuff(isnull(stuff(reverse(@input), 1+3, 0, @separator), reverse(@input)), 1+7, 0, @separator), isnull(stuff(reverse(@input), 1+3, 0, @separator), reverse(@input))))
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
  select col, len(col) - 3 pos from tablename
  union all 
  select 
    cast(left(col, pos) + '-' + right(col, len(col) - pos) as varchar(100)), 
    pos - 3
  from cte
  where pos > 0
)
select col from cte
where pos <= 0
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ca706f4e628237642f050c1e5dfff039).
Results:

```
> | col         |
> | :---------- |
> | 8           |
> | 476         |
> | 845-907-392 |
> | 45-907-392  |
> | 4-767       |
```